# Stop APIs calls with different query param + RTK query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Let's assume we have an API with a query param which keeps changing as a timestamp

```
https://example.com/api/example?timestamp=1684522021000
```

once using RTK hook

```
const timestamp = dayjs().unix() * 1000;

const query = useFetchDataQuery(
    `example.com/api/example?${timestamp}`,
  );
```

If API get fails, it keeps calling the API until the app crashes:

[image]

I tried using retry solution, skip solution but every time RTK considers it as a new API.

Comment: The `timestamp` queryString parameter doesn't really seem relevant to the query. You should probably append that to the API request in the endpoint instead of making it part of the query arg passed to the hook/endpoint. Does this make sense? If not, can you [edit] the post to share the api slice code?

Comment: plus timestamp, im sending  a signature which is create based on timestamp, hence i needs to send the signature as well which will be change by any request

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly all that means? From what I can tell, you just need some endpoint declarations that "inject" a queryString param for (*specific??*) requests, which is, or probably should be, separate from the "query" argument to the endpoint, e.g. URL, that the UI is triggering. Why is the query hook taking a domain + path + search string anyway? This is what the endpoints are for.

Comment: here is the case :
first create a signature by a post API call  with timestamp as payload(our won backend)
second add timestamp + signature as query params to send as get api  (binance server)
(binance requirements )

Comment: Ok, the signature sounds like it should be part of the query since there's a dependency on it being fetched previously, but the timestamp just seems like extra "data" that is sent with the request for the backend to handle. Is this an accurate assessment based on your description or is the issue still completely unclear? Your post seems to be a bit of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), perhaps a [mcve] of the frontend API slice code and what you expect the backend to handle would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use skip to jump those cases

```
const { data } = useFetchDataQuery(
    { tenantKey, page: 0, size: 100 },
    { skip: !your variables },
  )
```

Comment: once API get failed (status 400) , then what should I use as variable ?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

Instead of using `useFetchDataQuery` hook, I used `useLazyFetchDataQuery` hook:

```
  const [getBalanceInfo, results] = useLazyFetchDataQuery();
```

and use it inside `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getBalanceInfo(
      `${
        END_POINT
      }?${timestampNow()}`
    );
  }, []);
```

Using `luseLazyQuery` returns a tuple with a trigger function, the query result, and last promise info. Similar to useQuery, but with manual control over when the data fetching occurs.

[More info](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery)

Answer (score -1):

```js
const cache = {};

async function useFetchDataQuery( url ){
    // Get full baseurl from input url
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute( 'href', url );
    const query = new URL( a.href );
    const baseurl = query.origin + query.pathname;

    // Set baseurl counter
    if( !cache[baseurl] ) cache[baseurl] = 0;

    // Exit if baseurl is requested more than 5 times
    if( cache[baseurl] >= 5 ) return;

    // Increment baseurl request
    cache[baseurl]++;
    
    // Fetch url
    return await fetch( url ).then( res => {
            // delete request from cache
            delete cache[baseurl];

            // return result
            return res.json();
        })
        .catch( error => {
            // log error
            console.error( error );

            // try again in 5 sec
            setTimeout( () => useFetchDataQuery( url ), 5000 );

            return null;
        });

}

useFetchDataQuery( `/api/example?timestamp=${timestamp}` );
```